# How do I add the Java API documentation to Intellij IDEA for offline use

Tags: java, api, intellij-idea, documentation

I know that you can link the url with the documentation to IntelliJ IDEA, but that only works when you are online. Since I'm offline most of the time, I wanted to have this backup on me all of the time.

Can you tell me where do I download it?

Is it added the same way I add the url for the online documentation?

How do I access the documentation once it has been downloaded and installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use case is described in [IntelliJ IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-offline.html#external-docs).

[image: offline external documentation]

The documentation is accessed as described in the [corresponding help section](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#external-docs).

[image: external docs]